# NoSuchMethodException - PerfIOPrefetchStart

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, nosuchmethoderror

My RecyclerViews are not showing in this activity, so I had a look in the LogCat when I was running the app on my phone, only to notice this error : do any of you know where it's from ? It seems (according to other posts here) that it could be linked to `Context()` or `SharedPreferences` but I can't see where their use would go wrong :

**Activity**

```
package com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class players extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> playerNames;
Button send;
PlayerAdapter Adapter;
RecyclerView playerList;
String[] names;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_players);

    playerNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    final ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    send = findViewById(R.id.b_send);



    Bundle extra = new Bundle();
    final int numPlayers = extra.getInt("numPlayers");
    System.out.println(numPlayers);
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
    {
        playerNames.add("Joueur " + (i+1) + " : ");
    }
    playerList = findViewById(R.id.player_list);
    playerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    Adapter = new PlayerAdapter(playerNames,this);
    playerList.setAdapter(Adapter);
    names = new String[numPlayers];



    Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
                players.add(new Player(names[i]));
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Score.class);
            intent.putExtra("players", players);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}



private class PlayerAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayerAdapter.PlayerHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> playerNames;
    private Context context;

    public PlayerAdapter (ArrayList<String> playerNames, Context context) {
        this.playerNames = playerNames;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public PlayerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v =

LayoutInflater.from(players.this).inflate(R.layout.list_cell, parent,
                        false);
        return new PlayerHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlayerHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.bind(this.playerNames.get(position));

        holder.mPlayerName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int
                    start, int before,
                                          int count) {
                names[position] = charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start,
                                      int before,
                                      int count){

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return playerNames.size();
    }



    public class PlayerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mPlayerLabel;
        EditText mPlayerName;


        public PlayerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mPlayerLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_label);
            mPlayerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_name);
        }

        public void bind(String playerName) {
            mPlayerLabel.setText(playerName);
            mPlayerName.setHint("Nom de " + playerName);
        }

        public String getData(){
            return mPlayerName.getText().toString();
        }

    }
}
}
```

**LogCat**

```
02-28 14:13:46.476 17413-17413/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-28 14:13:46.514 17413-17449/? E/zygote64: Failed sending reply to             debugger: Broken pipe
02-28 14:13:46.515 17413-17449/? I/zygote64: Debugger is no longer active
02-28 14:13:46.597 17413-17413/? D/Embryo: preload     com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch, 30ms, hwui=true, layout=false, decor=false
02-28 14:13:46.604 17413-17467/? I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 076f837, I801ffd6741
                                       Build Date                       :     10/24/17
                                       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version:     EV031.20.00.04
                                       Local Branch                     : 
                                       Remote Branch                    : 
                                       Remote Branch                    : 
                                       Reconstruct Branch               : 
02-28 14:13:46.604 17413-17467/? I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8998.so from the current namespace instead.
02-28 14:13:46.601 17413-17413/? W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:141319): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=16971 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
02-28 14:13:46.609 17413-17467/? I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
02-28 14:13:46.615 17413-17467/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-28 14:13:46.615 17413-17467/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
02-28 14:13:46.615 17413-17467/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
02-28 14:13:46.817 17413-17413/? E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
02-28 14:13:46.817 17413-17413/? E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
02-28 14:13:46.914 17413-17413/? D/AppTracker: App Event: start
02-28 14:13:47.012 17413-17467/? I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8998.so from the current namespace instead.
02-28 14:13:49.884 17413-17413/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
02-28 14:13:49.906 17413-17413/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
02-28 14:13:49.906 17413-17413/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
02-28 14:13:49.909 17413-17447/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=25KB
02-28 14:13:49.909 17413-17447/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch I/zygote64: After     code cache collection, code=30KB, data=25KB
02-28 14:13:49.909 17413-17447/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
02-28 14:13:49.917 17413-17413/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
02-28 14:13:49.917 17413-17413/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
02-28 14:13:49.923 17413-17413/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch I/System.out: 0
02-28 14:13:49.927 17413-17413/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch D/AppTracker: App Event: start
02-28 14:13:49.990 17413-17447/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=37KB, data=47KB
02-28 14:13:49.990 17413-17447/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=37KB, data=47KB
02-28 14:13:49.990 17413-17447/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
02-28 14:13:49.990 17413-17447/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
02-28 14:13:49.995 17413-17467/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x761eeb1400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x761e894f60
02-28 14:14:49.808 17413-17413/com.olirwin.spartacus.deutsch D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the fact that your `RecyclerView` isn't showing. I hope someone else knows what it is. I advise you to split the adapter in another file, so you would get something like this:

**Activity**

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> playerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button send;
    PlayerAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView playerList;
    String[] names;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_players);

        final ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
        send = findViewById(R.id.b_send);

        Bundle extra = new Bundle();
        final int numPlayers = extra.getInt("numPlayers");
        System.out.println(numPlayers);
        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
            playerNames.add("Joueur " + (i+1) + " : ");
        }
        playerList = findViewById(R.id.player_list);
        playerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new PlayerAdapter(playerNames,this);
        playerList.setAdapter(Adapter);
        names = new String[numPlayers];

        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
                    players.add(new Player(names[i]));
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Score.class);
                intent.putExtra("players", players);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class PlayerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayerListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> playerNames;
    private Context context;

    public PlayerListAdapter(ArrayList<String> playerNames, Context context) {
        this.playerNames = playerNames;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_cell);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(this.playerNames.get(position));

        holder.playerName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(
                    CharSequence charSequence, 
                    int start, 
                    int before,
                    int count) {
                names[position] = charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start,
                                      int before,
                                      int count) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return playerNames.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView playerLabel;
        EditText playerName;

        public PlayerHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            playerLabel = view.findViewById(R.id.player_label);
            playerName = view.findViewById(R.id.player_name);
        }

        public void bind(String playerName) {
            playerLabel.setText(playerName);
            playerName.setHint("Nom de " + playerName);
        }

        public String getData(){
            return playerName.getText().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Tip**

If the content in the `RecyclerView` doesn't change dynamically you can do `RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)` to improve performance.

Advise to you: try to be consistent and take a look at the Java coding conventions. Android Studio has auto-formatting (shortcut: ctrl + alt + L on Windows or option + command + L on Mac), so you can make your code look a bit cleaner.

Comment: Hi, do you think the content of the RecyclerView is not showing because I made it in one and only class ?

Comment: No, but it's just bad practice to stuff everything into one class. Did you get it to work with the code I provided?